# How do I create SQL script to create a new column in the dataset and generating a subcategory on each item if it matches another table?

Tags: google-bigquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNhLK.png)My business task is to match our sales data with subcategories based on UPCs in our master spreadsheet. That way, we can make better data viz comparing product sales within each subcategory. What is the best way to approach this problem?

I have 4 year's worth sales data that carries product name, quantity sold, and main categories per line. It does not have subcategories. I oversee the data through Connected Sheets, generate a pivot table with desired outputs in the rows and columns, and then I built a FILTER function/VLOOKUP function in google sheets in order to search for a product subcategory based on its UPC. Since the data set is huge, I am running into some problems where it would not produce subcategory results if its a discontinued item or if there are duplicates in my master list of subcategories per product.

I think it would be more efficient if I created a table of our items from our master spreadsheet and downloaded that table into Bigquery so that I would have a subcategory matched to the UPC code. From there, I'd create a query to have a new column generated in the sales data to populate a subcategory IF the UPC code of the product on the line would match the UPC on the table I've added.

Does that make sense? How would I go about doing that? What would the SQL look like in order to perform such task?

I haven't started the task yet, still exploring options on BigQuery and/or Connected Sheets. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are going to want to look up the ALTER command to change the table, and insert the new column for starters.

Comment: And you are going to have to look into the JOIN command if you want to do things where the data from 2 tables merge into a new table sort of thing.

Comment: If you use those commands you can then return some results to this post so we can attempt to help you with formatting.

Comment: @easleyfixed I was digging through this earlier this week and discovered yesterday the concept of data blending directly on Looker Studio. I was able to address the issue by linking the SKU of the sales dataset to the UPC of our master spreadsheet to pull the subcategory information. Thanks for the suggestion! This'll be plan B if I need to.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back your solution, I do hope those help you in the future.  Never used Looker Studio, but if its based on MySQL,  if you have not played with MS Workbench yet, it turns MySQL work into Excel file level difficulty.  Instead of hard typing ALTER table etc etc criteria, you can drag and drop in the UI and save yourself quite a bit of time on simple updates.